# GridView only takes first CSSClass in css file

Tags: css, asp.net

in my asp.net page I have three grid views

```html
<asp:GridView CssClass="GridA" ID="grid1" GridLines="Horizontal" HorizontalAlign="Center" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" onrowcommand="gridHand_RowCommand">
                    <Columns>
                        ...
                    </Columns>  
                    </asp:GridView>
 <asp:GridView CssClass="GridA" ID="grid2" GridLines="Horizontal" HorizontalAlign="Center" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" onrowcommand="gridHand_RowCommand">
                    <Columns>
                        ...
                    </Columns>  
                    </asp:GridView>
 <asp:GridView CssClass="GridA" ID="grid3" GridLines="Horizontal" HorizontalAlign="Center" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" onrowcommand="gridHand_RowCommand">
                    <Columns>
                        ...
                    </Columns>  
                    </asp:GridView>
```

and I have a CSS file in my Skins which looks as follows:

```html
.Grid {
    border-width: 0;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: aqua;
    color: BlanchedAlmond;
    width: 200px;
}

.GridA {
    border-width: 0;
    border-style:none;
    background-color: DarkBlue;
    color: BlanchedAlmond;
    width: 200px;
}
```

As a result, NO css class is assigned. The gridviews stay in their default shape.
If I apply the css class "Grid" instead of "GridA", it is working.

If I swap the two CSS definitions in my css file, it is the opposite: The css layout gets only applied if "Grid" is assigned to the gridviews.

Or to say it the simple way: The gridviews only take the first (!) css definition in my css file, never the second one.

Why?

Comment: your elements do not seem to have `Grid` class ( besides `GridA` ) can you reproduce this behavior in a snippet? ( add both HTML and CSS in the same snippet , you have different sections for the different languages )

Comment: What I meant is when I write "<asp:GridView CssClass="GridA"..." instead of "<asp:GridView CssClass="Grid" it is working.

Comment: You might have some styles for `.Grid` class in a more specific selector. Did you `inspect` in dev console to see if the styles are loaded or not ? or if they are overwritten by something ? and what did you mean by `Or to say it the simple way: The gridviews only take the first (!) css definition in my css file, never the second one.` ? Maybe you have an unclosed `}` . We need an example that reproduces the problem otherwise we cannot help you

Comment: Hi. Actually I found out that on Chrome and Edge everything is working as desired but not on Firefox, which is giving the behaviour described above. Anyway, the preferred browser for my appication is Chrome, so this should be fine then.